# jQuery: переназначения методов

Tags: jquery, javascript, html

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему такая конструкция отказывается работать.

```
<body>
   <div id="content">
   </div>
</body>

<script>
$(function() {
    $('#content').load('../include/index.php');
})
</script>
```

Проблема в том что если контент из файла index.php просто вставить в id="content" то jQuery методы работают хорошо, а если контент загрузить методом .load то многие функции перестают работать. Знаю что с помощью метода .live события сохраняют свою работоспособность.

Например:

```
$('button').live('click', function() {
    //Действие
})
```

Но как быть с функциями, особенно когда их много. Конечно можно скрипты подгружать и вместе с подгружаемым файлом, но это будет не правильно, зачем каждый раз подгружать скрипты.

Просто я использую jQuery плагин `cookie` и после загрузки контента через .load плагин `cookie` уже не работает.

Подскажите решение проблемы.

Comment: обработчики о которых вы говорите вешаются по загрузке основной страницы?

Comment: `.load()` предназначен не для того чтобы  грузить страницы целиком, а для того, чтобы обновлять какие-то данные без особых телодвижений, блок новостей там или набор баннеров. *держите скрипты в файлах .js грузите их через `<script src=` , если необходимо загрузить скрипт, читайте [`$.getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) - там есть пример как сделать кэширующий загрузчик.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для начала, про метод *live()* пора бы уже забыть, писалось сотни раз. Используете метод **.on()**. Во-вторых, при работе с динамически подгружаемым контентом, я бы рекомендовал [делегированную обработку](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/On#.D0.9F.D1.80.D1.8F.D0.BC.D0.B0.D1.8F_.D0.B8_.D0.B4.D0.B5.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.B3.D0.B8.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.8F_.D0.BE.D0.B1.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B1.D0.BE.D1.82.D0.BA.D0.B0_.28.D0.BF.D0.B0.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.82.D1.80_selector.29). К примеру, если у вас основной контейнер не изменяется, то вешаете событие отталкиваясь от него.

```
$('#container').on('click', '.elem', function(e){
    // ...
});
```

В таком случае, как бы переиндексируется внутренний код этого контейнера и находится нужный элемент. Злоупотреблять этим так же не надо, т.к. все эти телодвижения влияют на скорость. И старайтесь находить максимально близкий родительский элемент, а не body, к примеру.

Comment: > В таком случае после загрузки страницы на загруженный контент через .load скрипты не отреагируют.

Не хотите ли вы сказать, что вы загружаете не часть контента, а всю страницу? Если нет, подгрузка контента не должна влиять на работу плагина jquery.cookie.js. Кроме того, почему бы не использовать LocalStorage? Или религия не позволяет? ))

Comment: Верно, у меня подгружается только часть контента но почему то jquery.cookie.js не срабатывает. Если бы подгружалась вся страница то таких проблем бы не было так как со страницей подгружались бы и скрипты. За LocalStorage спасибо. Подскажите если кто знает как хотя бы сформировать google запрос на эту тему, дабы черпнуть по больше инфы.

Comment: @Berserker, запрос по вашей проблеме? Так проблема, я практически уверен, частного характера. По ссылке, которую вы дали выше, понять что-то сложно. Выложите пусть и с ошибками, но работающий вариант, где у вас должна подгружаться страница, тогда можно будет как-то въехать в общую картину. Пока могу сказать, что для начала, надо поубирать из html весь js-код (типа onclick) и перенести всё в js-файл: "*Котлеты отдельно, мухи отдельно*". Повесить обработчики событий на ссылки, обернув всё в конструкцию DOMReady.

Comment: Вот ссылка http://mywork.zz.mu/metro/ здесь в файле js/applications.js который находится внизу html страницы стоит .load который подгружает контент в id="metro". В данный момент при перемещении блоков coockie не сохроняются, если же не подгружать контент, а просто его вставить в id="metro", то coockie срабатывают.

Comment: @Berserker, ну так порядок выполнения у вас в этом случае: сначала попытаться установить/проверить куки (файл *jquery.sortable.js*), а только потом - подгрузить контент (файл *applications.js*). Вот попробуйте в файле *jquery.sortable.js* подгружать контент в месте, которое я показал ниже.

    $(function() {
 // here, we allow the user to sort the items
        $(setSelector).load('include/index.php'); // вот в этом месте (!!!)
        $(setSelector).sortable({
        // ....

Comment: Блин, к сожалению такой метод не прокатил. Если тебе еще интересно могу поделится кодом.

Answer (score 0):

Блин не поверишь но решение было таким

```
$(setSelector).load('../include/index.php', function() {
    restoreOrder();
});
```

Comment: @Berserker, Почему ж не поверю? )) Всё логично - после подгрузки контента, в коллбэке вызываете функцию.

Comment: Спасибо за направление моей извилины в правильном направлении )))