# jQuery метод .on

Tags: jquery

Не как не пойму почему такой метод не работает

```
$('div').on('click', function() {
    $('body').hide();
})
```

При старой библиотеки .live работал на ура. А в новой .on ваще ни как не пашет.  Везде пишут что именно так как я написал должно работать, но ничего не работает. Хотя вот так работает.

```
$(document).on('click','div', function() {
    $('body').hide();
})
```

В чем проблема, или же метод .on только так и должен работать ???

Comment: Версия Jquery какая?

Comment: jquery-1.9.1.min.js

Comment: весь код страницы нужен

Comment: Весь код это много, у меня идет подгрузка контента через .load, так что здесь много файлов. Просто надо событие повесить на еще не существующий элемент. Вообщем то работает, вот так:

    $('div').on({click: function(){
        $('.hover-bg').show();
    }})

Comment: Хотя на сайте jQuery в документации написано что должно работать так как я написал в первом варианте. Сколько я не бился никогда он у меня не работал. Вот зачем они убрали .live ??? Ведь с ним было все проще, зачем все усложнять :(

Comment: Если интересно, то вы можете посмотреть, почему убрали live(), там большой такой список проблем: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Вот нахера они убрали .live ??? Ведь с
>   ним было все проще

Тут вы ошибаетесь, просто не разобрались. Первое, что вызывает недоумение, так этот кусочек кода:

```
$('body').hide();
```

Вы скрываете неотъемлимый тэг разметки. Не логичней ли было обернуть весь внутренний код в какой-нибудь блок  и манипулировать им? Во вторых, по поводу метода **on()**: подустал уже писать, поэтому даю [ссылку на предыдущий ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/191794/javascript-jquery-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2).

Comment: Это

    $('body').hide();

 я просто так написал дабы было видно что имеется действие

Comment: @Berserker, А вот "просто так" - лучше не надо )) Мы же рассматриваем и логически выстроенные последовательности событий и зависимости элементов друг от друга, что при методе on() - является основополагающим.

Comment: То есть хочешь сказать что данное действие может повлиять на выполнения метода ???

Comment: @Berserker, при определенных условиях - естественно влияет. Поэтому я и советую показывать или же реальный код, или же идентичный оригиналу.

Comment: Ок. Буду знать на будущее.

Answer (score 1):

Может стоит [почитать документацию на .on()?](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

> **Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements**; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().
> ...
> If new HTML is being injected into the page, select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is placed into the page. Or, use delegated events to attach an event handler, as described next.

Вкратце переведу, что там написано: обработчик события можно повесить только на существующий элемент, но есть возможность обрабатывать события от элементов, которые были добавлены после. Для этого необходимо повесить обработчик на существующий родительский элемент (например document или body), определить тип события (click), селектор (div) и функцию. Данный обработчик будет слушать все всплывающие события и реагирует только на те, которые произошли от фильтруемых селектором элементов.

Так-то.

Comment: Все всем спасибо! Вопрос закрываю.

Answer (score 0):

Короче нашел решение:

Если делать вот так

```
$('div').on({click: function(){
    $('.selector').show();
}})
```

То в таком варианте клик будет работать только на элемент `div` если в место `div`-а написать класс или айди, то работать ничего не будет.

Что бы вешать события на еще не созданные DOM элементы то надо делать вот так:

```
$(document).on({mouseenter: function() {
    $('.selector').show();
},
mouseleave: function() {
    $('.selector').hide();
}}, '.hoverSelector');
```

В таком случае после создания на странице новых элементов на элементы с классом `.hoverSelector` будет вешаться событие `.hover` а точнее: при наведении `.selector` будет появляться, ну а в противном случае исчезать.

Comment: Кстати желательно в место `$(document)` писать приближенный элемент родитель.

Comment: Я добавил ответ, который объясняет поведение функции .on()