# Запретить переход по ссылке после подгрузки контента

Tags: javascript, jquery

На странице http://x359.ru/ контент подгружает api depositphotos 
Хочется запретить переход по ссылке после подгрузки контента.

```
<script>
    window.onload = function(e){ 
        $('a').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('Переход по ссылке запрещён !');
        });
    }   
</script>
```

Comment: Странно , у меня работает , да и не только у меня.<http://i.imgur.com/Zr7tiBD.png>

Comment: По какой ссылке-то?

Comment: Перенес на другой домен < http://x359.ru/ >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно вас понял, вы не хотите, чтобы при клике по ссылкам срабатывал переход. 
У вас на странице есть указанный вами код и он, видимо, не работает так, как вы ожидаете. 
Я вижу в исходном коде страницы ссылки вида

```
<a href=37><li>Текстуры</li></a>
```

в то время, как на готовой странице ссылки содержат полные адреса. Я полагаю, какой-то скрипт у вас на странице обработал эти ссылки? Если да - скорее всего, здесь и кроется ответ. Вы повесили событие на ссылки, а потом другой скрипт удалил эти объекты из DOM и заменил их другими. Понятное дело, события больше не срабатывают, т.к. элементы "уже не те".

Попробуйте заменить код на

```
$(function(e){ 
    $(window).on('click', 'a', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Переход по ссылке запрещён !');
    });
})
```

Про методы .live, .on и делегирование вообще [сказано уже много](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/191794/jquery-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2).

Comment: Вставил Ваш код, и удалил ссылки на категории, чтобы не путаться. По клику на изображение все равно переходит по ссылке.

Comment: Всё получилось, спасибо,Иван.