# Отлов появившихся элементов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пишу сайт который полностью будет использовать ajax. Все работает до тех пор, пока я не загружаю новый элемент, при нажатии на который вызвается какая-то функция - он просто не работает, так как приходится снова отсеивать все элементы. Первый вариант - отлавливать изменения DOM, но я заметил что мои события плодятся, и нажатия на кнопку работают уже по нескольку раз.
Работает таким образом:

```
document.getElementById("put").addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", function (event) {
  $('.list a, #ajax').click(function() {
    $("body").attr("style","-webkit-filter: blur(5px);-moz-filter: blur(5px);-o-filter: blur(5px);-ms-filter: blur(5px);filter: blur(5px);");
    path  = $(this).attr("href");
    $.ajax({
      url: path+'?ajax=true',
      success: function(data){
        json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);   
        $('.content').html(json.content);
        document.title = "HR | " + json.title;
        $('.list a').attr("class",null);
        $('.list a:contains("'+json.title+'")').attr("class","active");
        history.replaceState({back: location.pathname, next: path}, json.title, path);
        $(".side").html(json.sidebar);
        $("body").attr("style","");
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
}, false);
```

Подскажите как заставить это все работать нормально.

Если для кто-то не понял суть - вот [демо](http://w-0rld.ru/works/).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [jQuery: переназначения методов](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/191794/jquery-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2)

Answer (score 3):

Как обычно, используем делегирование событий - прикрепляем обработчик к родителю, который всегда существует, с указанием фильтра элементов, для которых предназначен этот обработчик (http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
//document.getElementById("put").addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", function (event) {
  $("body").on("click", '.list a, #ajax', function() {
    $("body").attr("style","-webkit-filter: blur(5px);-moz-filter: blur(5px);-o-filter: blur(5px);-ms-filter: blur(5px);filter: blur(5px);");
    var path  = $(this).attr("href"); // !!! make it local variable
    $.ajax({
      url: path+'?ajax=true',
      success: function(data){
        json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);   
        $('.content').html(json.content);
        document.title = "HR | " + json.title;
        $('.list a').attr("class",null);
        $('.list a:contains("'+json.title+'")').attr("class","active");
        history.replaceState({back: location.pathname, next: path}, json.title, path);
        $(".side").html(json.sidebar);
        $("body").attr("style","");
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
//}, false);
```

PS: обратите внимание на `var` перед переменной `path` - в Вашем эта глобальная переменная может измениться между вызовом `$.ajax` и выполнением асинхронного обработчика `success`.

Comment: Спасибо за быстрый ответ. Интересно, а чем .on отличается от простого .click?

Comment: @W_0rld добавил пояснение